# JavaFX: dosent matter the code i write , it always appear a blank "hello word" GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

it doesn't matter the code I write
it ALWAYS shows up a blank empty GUI with "hello world" title on it
while I NEVER setTitle or wrote "hello world" on my code
this video will explain everything

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDgKtqfNFfw

here is my code :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    Button button;
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("123456");
        button=new Button("Convert");
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene s= new Scene(layout,300,250);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your development environment may be loading a different `Main.class`. Your code works fine for me on the command line: `javac Main.java && java Main`.

Comment: yea the IDE was executing the Sample generated Main , instead of the main that i manually created ! Prob solved , Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384673/javafx-dosent-matter-the-code-i-write-it-always-appear-a-blank-hello-word-g?noredirect=1#comment104961176_59384673) to your question, there is no problem with your code, and you should check the configuration which you are running. Try checking the following:

- The Java class which is being loaded by the Intellij Idea
- If it is different from Main.class, change it

If nothing helps, try creating a new project in Intellij Idea without any template and create new configuration from ground-up; it will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Oh my bad! Now I understand.
The problem is that I ignored the generated sample `Main` and I manually created another main class; I work with it; 
and when I run, the IDE run the sample main instead of my main.